# Conversion de fechas php desde variable

Tags: php

Tengo un campo que es una cadena de un rango de fechas:

```
$periodo = "12/04/2021 - 14/04/2021";
```

Intento insertar cada fecha en un array `$array_fechas[]` para cambiarle el formato a cada una pero no me devuelve el resultado esperado.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$periodo = "12/04/2021 - 14/04/2021";

$array_fechas = explode(" - ", $periodo);

$fecha_inicio = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($array_fechas[0]));
$fecha_final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($array_fechas[1]));

echo $fecha_inicio."<br>";
echo $fecha_final;
```

El resultado que deseo es el siguiente:

```
2021-04-12
2021-04-14
```

Pero el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
2021-12-04
1970-01-01
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: @BetaM Lo he intentado pero nosé como poder hacerlo con `createFromFormat`

Comment: @BetaM Si señor, mucho mejor, en la parte donde dice "Las fechas en los formatos m/d/y o d-m-y no son ambiguas"  https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que está pasando es que el formato de fechas que estás usando no es el adecuado, cuando se usa `/` para separar las fechas, `strtotime` asume que estás usando el formato norteamericano que es `m/d/y`, o sea, mes, día y año. Mientras que cuando se usa por separador el `-` o `.`, `strtotime` asume que se está usando el formato europeo, o sea, día, mes y año.
Ambas situaciones se solucionan usando el formato internacional, o sea `Y-m-d`, año, mes y día.

Pero para solucionar tu problema, puedes hacer uso de la función `str_replace` para reemplazar los `/` por `-` y usar el formato europeo.

```
$periodo = "12/04/2021 - 14/04/2021";
$periodo = str_replace('/', '-', $periodo); /*Este es el código añadido*/
$array_fechas = explode(" - ", $periodo);


$fecha_inicio = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($array_fechas[0]));
$fecha_final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($array_fechas[1]));

echo $fecha_inicio."<br>";
echo $fecha_final;
```

Adjunto las referencias del manual de PHP, por si quieres saber más:

STRTOTIME: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php

STR_REPLACE: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Perfecto! Funcionó! Muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

si ya tienes la fecha, intenta hacer esto, haber si te sirve

```
<?php
$fecha = '12/04/2021';
$fecha_format = date_create_from_format("d/m/Y", $fecha);
echo date_format($fecha_format, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando son fechas que no vienen con un formato UTC, es decir, Y-m-d, es común que las fechas en PHP te puedan ocasionar problemas. PHP tiene [suficientes métodos para ayudarte](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), uno de estos es `createFromFormat`.

Lo que puedes intentar es algo de la siguiente manera:

```
$periodo = "12/04/2021 - 14/04/2021";

$array_fechas = explode(" - ", $periodo);

$inicio = new DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $array_fechas[0]);

$fin = new DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $array_fechas[1]);

print_r($inicio->format('Y-m-d'));

print_r($fin->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Ten en mente que también tienes el método [date_create_from_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php) que es una alias de lo que acabamos de hacer más arriba. Así también podrías hacer:

```
$inicio = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $array_fechas[0]);

$fin = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $array_fechas[1]);

print_r($inicio->format('Y-m-d'));

print_r($fin->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Y te daría el mismo resultado. Puedes mirarlo [acá](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9776b3d5dcda756435708ede36c63784461fb86d)